# Angularjs 'ng-repeat' does not recognize 'data' array of HTTP response

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, httpresponse

I'm creating a small application using Angularjs and Spring boot. I want to display a list of data using Angularjs ng-repeat directive.

**What I expect :**

[image]

**But the actual result :**

[image]

When I run the code,the data which are supposed to display using ng-repeat are not display although the HTTP response 'data' are assigned to 'images' array, does anyone can figure out the reason to this behavior ?

---

HTML Code ( ng-repeat )

```
 <p>Array : {{images}}</p>
 <h3 ng-repeat="x in images">{{x}}</h3>
```

Angularjs code to set data to images array

```
$http.get(url, data, config).then(function (response) {
                if (response != null) {
                    $scope.images = response.data;
                } else {
                }
            }, function (response) {
            });
```

Http response

```
config: {method: "GET", transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), paramSerializer: ƒ, publisher: "test", …}
data: (5) ["Data 1", "Data 2", "Data 3", "Data 4", "Data 5"]
headers: ƒ (d)
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: post what you have JSON.stringify(response.data);

Comment: Can you see any message on console ?

Comment: @ShashankVivek yes there was a message  **Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]** and the reason for the above behavior was, there were **duplicate data** in the original 'data' array. ( original data array contained about 30 data ). and thank you for directing me :)

Comment: @theGlobalVariable : Cheers mate. You can refer `track by $index` if you might expect `duplicate` data. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code might not be running the digest cycle.  Try throwing your `$scope.images = response.data;` into a `$timeout` which will cause the digest cycle to run.

```
$timeout(function() {
  $scope.images = response.data;
}, 0)
```

Comment: Why would the `digest` cycle not run if its a promise of `$http`?

Comment: @ShashankVivek No idea without getting my hands on his code to diagnose why it might not be running, but if the value is getting assigned properly to `$scope.images` then the only explanation I can think of is the digest cycle not running.

Comment: Yep, but if this is happening then we have a major bug in AngularJS itself. ;) . No offence I just highlighted that your answer contradicts with the core `angularJs` concepts. `$digest` cant be missed if the question says what it says.

Comment: @ShashankVivek No offense taken.  Not having the DOM update after the `$digest` cycle properly runs also seems like it would be a major bug in AngularJS.  Granted I'm assuming he doesn't have an error somewhere else in his code preventing the DOM from loading.

Comment: Thank you @BShaps about your thoughts :) . The cause for the above behavior was duplicate data in the array

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = ['Data1','Data2','Data3'];
$scope.images = JSON.stringify(a);//"[\"Data1\",\"Data2\",\"Data3\"]"
```

you should check whether the data is a JSON string, and use JSON.parse() to convert it into array .cause angular's 'ng-repeat' accept JSON format

var myJSON = JSON.parse(JSONStr);

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your support @John :) The cause for the issue was duplicate data in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.get(url, data, config).then(function(response) {
    if (response != null) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.images = response.data;
        });
    } else {}
}, function(response) {

});
```